# как работает std::move?

Tags: c++

Возник следующий вопрос: как работает std::move с точки зрения склейки ссылок?

Вопрос возник в связи с прохождением курса на платформе stepic  - "Программирование на языке C++ (продолжение)"

Уточнение: последующий вопрос и его "не полезность" в глазах сообщества SO , никак не отражает стремление автора вопроса "не разобраться в вопросе" или напливательское отношение при его формировании. 
Данный вопрос был задан в соответсвии с материалами вышеупомянутого курса и никак не может быть более информативнее, чем последний.

Как std::move ведет себя с rvalue и lvalue ссылками?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "склейки ссылок"?

Comment: @VTT, добавил изображение примера

Comment: Ок, а при чем тут `std::move`?

Comment: @VTT, как я понял, принцип его работы - базируется именно на этом. std::move это шаблонная функция, которая использует семантику преобразования ссылок?

Comment: `move` делает `static_cast<remove_reference_t<T>&&>(t)` возвращая rvalue с типом rvalue reference to T, никакого профита от использования универсальных ссылок не получает

Comment: Вы сейчас CSC антирекламу сделали :)

Comment: @isnullxbh, ну уж простят меня, не со зла спрашиваю, а потому что не понял)

Comment: В отличие от указателей быть ссылку на ссылку нельзя. Поэтому T& & должно быть нечто бессмысление. Поэтому и сделали запись T&&. T&& это T&, где компилятору явно намекаатся, что объект T после выполнения функции не нужен, его можно ломать. Выходит, что T&& это немёк компилятору, что T можно ломать, а функция void foo(T&& t), после выполнения сломает t. T&&&, T&& && и т.д. не имеет смысла и компилироваться не должны. std::move принимает T& (ссылку на объект, который по мнению компилятора ломать нельзя) , и возвращает T&& (ссылку на объект, который ломать можно). Ничего больше он делать не умеет

Comment: @VTT, Comuter Science Center

Comment: @VTT, извините, не увидел вовремя. Все верно, это Computer Science Club.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко Ваш комментарий - полная ахинея.

Comment: @VTT, поторопился, конечно, Center.

Comment: Правила коллапса ссылок используются (могут использоваться) в работе `std::forward`. А `std::move` они низачем не нужны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. `std::move` это *безусловное* преобразование любого типа к rvalue-ссылке. Для этого происходит «очистка» входящего типа от ссылочности, с последующим «навязыванием» `&&`.